# Cannot use defaulted default constructor of 'Bar' within 'Foo' outside of member functions because 'value' has an initializer

Tags: c++, xcode

This following code runs fine under Visual Studio, however, it is causing a compile error under Xcode.

```
class Foo{
public:
    struct Bar {
        bool value = false;
        Bar() = default;
    };
    Foo(const Bar& bar = Bar()) { }
};
```

Error message:

> Cannot use defaulted default constructor of 'Bar' within 'Foo' outside of member functions because 'value' has an initializer

The error message above doesn't really make sense to me and I tried changing `Bar() = default` to `Bar() {}` since it mentioned *default constructor*. And surprisingly, it compiles alright.

But I still want to understand the problem here. Why I cannot use the default initializer if the member variable (`value` here in this case) has an initial value?